# Segmentation Fault in Zend Framework2 trying to add to sqlite db

Tags: php, sqlite, apache2, segmentation-fault, zend-framework2

I am currently trying to get around with the [Zend Framework 2 Tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/overview.html).

I am using an Apache 2 and php 5.4.7 with Zend Engine v2.4.0 on a Solaris system.

I managed to create everything I need but when I want to add or delete an album from my list the Apache child process always crashes giving a segmentation fault.
I backtraced this with 
gdb httpd, 
run -X
until the error occurs,
found out that the frame where something is executed for the last time tries to get the function isValid() of Zend's StringLength.php:169

When adding or editing an Album the user has to provide the data for the artist and the album name, then hits the submit button.
It's crashing now on validating the input of the form.

I tried adding single character names, üöä containing names and just simple names like 'simon the cat', everything fails.

Do you have any suggestion what the problem might be?

EDIT:

I localized the error a little more.

```
public function isValid($value)
{
    if (!is_string($value)) {
        $this->error(self::INVALID);
        return false;
    }
/*
    $this->setValue($value);
    if ($this->getEncoding() !== null) {
        $length = iconv_strlen($value, $this->getEncoding());
    } else {
        $length = iconv_strlen($value);
    }

    if ($length < $this->getMin()) {
        $this->error(self::TOO_SHORT);
    }
*/
    if (null !== $this->getMax() && $this->getMax() < $length) {
        $this->error(self::TOO_LONG);
    }

    if (count($this->getMessages())) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Segmentation fault raises beetween the comments in isValid(). 
Maybe its related to the getEncoding() method?

EDIT2:

Problem is connected with iconv_strlen, dunno why though :/ Works fine if you just use a normal strlen()

Comment: So, I didn't solve the problem.
I'm just using the normal strlen() now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you exactly are trying to do.

It seems that you are using some validation class: Zend\Validator\StringLength? Or am I wrong?

Can you provide your initial data for validator?